# How to convert to Xunit using mocking

Tags: xamarin.forms, mocking, xunit

I have these two methods in my service class

```
public class PatientService : IPatientService
{
    private readonly IRestClient _restClient;
    private readonly IAppSettings _appSettings;

    public PatientService(IRestClient restClient, IAppSettings appSettings)
    {
        _restClient = restClient;
        _appSettings = appSettings;
    }

    public async Task<IList<PatientViewModel>> GetPatients(int wardId)
    {
        var url = _appSettings.Server + _appSettings.PatientServiceEndPoint + wardId;
        var token = _appSettings.Token;
        return GetPatientList(await _restClient.GetAsync<List<PatientInfo>>(url, token));
    }

    public IList<PatientViewModel> GetPatientList(IList<PatientInfo> patientInfoList)
    {
        return patientInfoList.Select(p => new PatientViewModel(p)).ToList();
    }
}
```

I need to add this code to my Xunit.cs. How to do it?

I've implemented this and I do not know how to proceed.

```
private readonly PatientListPageViewModel _patientListPageViewModel;        
private readonly Mock<IPatientService> _patient;

public PatientServiceTests()
{
    _patient = new Mock<IPatientService>();
    _patientListPageViewModel = new PatientListPageViewModel(_patient.Object);          
}

[Fact]
public void GetListByWard_PassingWardId_GetPatientsCountAccordingToWardId()
{


}
```

This is what I tried to do. How to convert those two methods in service to be testable?

Comment: What is the subject under test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did get mocking a bit wrong. It is not the *component under test* that is mocked, but its *dependencies*. When unit-testing you'd like to test a unit in isolation. Your case of mocking would be kind of correct if you unit-tested the `PatientListPageViewModel`, but since your test class is named `PatientServiceTests` I assume that you really wanted to test `PatientService`. If you wanted to test the former, you would be quite right to mock `IPatientService`, but when testing `PatientService`, `IRestClient` and `IAppSettings` shall be mocked

```
public PatientServiceTests()
{
    _restClientMock = new Mock<IRestClient>();
    _appSettingsMock = new Mock<IAppSettings>();

    _patientService = new PatientService(_restClientMock.Object, _appSettingsMock.Object);         
}
```

And your test could be something like

```
[Fact]
public async Task ReturnsCorrectPatientList() // async supported as of xUnit 1.9
{
    // set up the mock
    _restClientMock.SetUp(restClient => restClient.GetAsync<List<Patient>>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
                   .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(/* what patients it shall return */));
    var result = await _patientService.GetPatients(0);
    // compare whether the returned result matches your expectations
}
```

If you wanted to test whether the URL is formed correctly, you could use `Verify`

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("SERVER", "ENDPOINT", 12, "1234", "SERVERENDPOINT12")]
[InlineData("https://localhost:65000", "/patients/", 5, https://localhost:65000/patients/5")]
public void TestWhetherCorrectUrlIsCalled(string server, string endpoint, int wardId, string token, string expectedUrl)
{
    _appSettingsMock.SetupGet(appSettings => appSettings.Server).Returns(server);
    _appSettingsMock.SetupGet(appSettings => appSettings.PatientServiceEndPoint).Returns(endpoint);
    _appSettingsMock.SetupGet(appSettings => appSettings.Token).Returns(token);

    _restClientMock.SetUp(restClient => restClient.GetAsync<List<Patient>>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
                   .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new List<Patient>()));

    // we do not need the result
    await _patientService.GetPatients(wardId);

    _restClientMock.Verify(restClient => restClient.GetAsync<List<Patient>>(exptectedUrl, token), Times.Once);
}
```

We are setting up the `IRestClient` in this case, since it would return `null` otherwise. And `await null` would cause your test to fail. After `GetPatients` has been called we are using `Verify` to verify that `GetAsync` has been called with the correct parameters. If it has not been called, `Verify` will throw and your test will fail. `Times.Once` means, that `GetAsync` shall have been called once and only once.

**On a side note**: Viewmodels shall have a meaning in the context of your user interface only. Services shall be independent and hence not return viewmodels, as you did, but POCOs (or maybe domain models). In this case the interface of your service should be

```
public interface IPatientService 
{
    public async Task<IList<Patient>> GetPatients(int wardId);
    // ...
}
```